# Get the size of an interface in systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have an interface with 2 modports, and the interface consists of multiple wires, hence when used as modport of a module it translates to multiple inputs and multiple outputs.

Is there a way to get the number of wires (or ports) inside the interface?

i.e something like

```
$size(my_interface)
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such way in system verilog. However, you can write your own vpi-based function to get this information.

Answer (score 1):

SystemVerilog does not provide built-in way of doing this. There are two options I can think of

1. Write a VPI introspection routine to discover the size
2. Provide a function in the interface that manually calculates the size.